# Django APScheduler not executing jobs according to schedule with Apache and mod_wsgi

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, apscheduler

I have a Django project that uses [django-apscheduler](https://github.com/jarekwg/django-apscheduler) with the following configuration:

---

#### Apache virtualhost

```
WSGIPassAuthorization On

WSGIScriptAlias / /some/app/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess some-app \
        user=someapp threads=15 display-name=some-app \
        python-path=/some/app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup some-app
```

#### Scheduled tasks

```
from pytz import utc

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from django_apscheduler.jobstores import DjangoJobStore, register_events, register_job

from administration.scheduled_tasks import add_db_backup, delete_old_db_backups

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(timezone=utc)
scheduler.add_jobstore(DjangoJobStore(), 'default')

register_events(scheduler)

@register_job(scheduler, 'cron', hour='0', minute='0')
def db_backups_job():
    add_db_backup()
    delete_old_db_backups()

scheduler.start()
```

---

As expected, the scheduled job is visible in Django admin. Also, the jobs execute *sometimes*, for example the daily job above has executed seven times during this month, although today is 15th and it should thus have executed 15 times. Note that I have restarted Apache during this time.

This seems to be a process lifetime issue. It seems that the `mod_wsgi` process is suspended and thus APScheduler jobs cannot run.

What is the lifetime of the `mod_wsgi` process? How can I assure that the jobs execute according to schedule or at least daily?

Comment: To be in control of process lifetime, you could run the Django app in its own process with, say Gunicorn and use Apache mod_proxy_http as a reverse proxy.

Comment: Also, apscheduler maintainer recommended to run the scheduler in a separate process, outside of Django.

Comment: Another thing to note - the scheduler should be launched from urls.py, see https://github.com/jarekwg/django-apscheduler/blob/master/examples/example_apscheduler/example_apscheduler/urls.py